# Gulp sass compilation issues

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I'm facing an issue on Sass compilation with Gulp.
I've some variables defined in a file, *_typos.scss*, like this:

```
$AristaFont : "Arista", Trebuchet MS, sans-serif;
```

And when I use this variable in another file,*_layout_header.scss*, Gulp say the variable is not defined:

```
[gulp-sass] sass/layout/_layout-header.scssError: Undefined variable: "$AristaFont".
        on line 107 of sass/layout/_layout-header.scss
```

These files are located in different folder like:

- sass/layout/_layout-header.scss
- sass/global/_typos.scss

Is it a problem for gulp-sass ? It wasn't with compass.

Thanks
EDIT: an excerpt of the application.scss witch import all scss files.

```
@import "global/_typos.scss";
@import "global/_style.scss";
@import "global/_flex.scss";
@import "global/_stacktable.scss";
/*@import "global/sub-nav";*/

// Import des partiels du layout du thème Drupal

@import "layout/_layout.scss";
@import "layout/_layout-nodes.scss";
@import "layout/_layout-nodes-flexbox.scss";
@import "layout/_layout-header.scss";
@import "layout/_layout-footer.scss";
```

My package.json excerpt:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "event-stream": "^3.3.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.6.3",
    "gulp-size": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "node-sass-import-once": "^1.2.0",
    "notify-send": "^0.1.2",
    "typey": "^1.1.1"
  },
```

Comment: Can you also post the file in which you are doing the `@import` of all the other sass files?

Comment: Is the definition placed in a file named _\_typos.scss_ or _typos.scss_? If it's in a file named _typos.scss_, that's where your error lies as you're including one with an underscore.

Comment: the file name is ``_typos.scss``

Comment: do I need to install libsass manually ? because gulp-sass install node-sass as dependency but I don't have libass node module.See edit.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Have you tried importing them the new modern way. @import "global/typos" - even if the file has an underscore in front. No scss

Comment: not yet.I will do .The issue come from Gulp seem not to recompile all files when I modifiy one, so it doesn't find some variables.I'll Tell you.

Comment: I changed all imports by your way, seem to work better, but I have many things to fix also.

Comment: @Mauricio Happen again, and I see if I recompile after editing the first imported file, CSS is good, more I edit  a scss file in the bottom of the application.sccs list, uncomplete compilation is more and more important and css file miss more items. Strange issue about this hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

```
please use this way:
in gulpfile.js file use this code:
//////////////////////////////////////////
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

/**
--Top level function--
  gulp.task = Define task
  gulp.src = Point topfiles to use
  gulp.dest = Points to folder to output
  gulp.watch = watch files and folder for change
**/

//Log message
gulp.task('message', () =>
  console.log("gulp is running... ")
);

//optimise images
gulp.task('imageMin', () =>
 gulp.src("images/**/*")
 .pipe(imagemin())
 .pipe(gulp.dest("img_min"))
);


//compile sass
gulp.task('sass',() =>
  gulp.src("sass/**/*.scss")
  .pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("css"))
);

//concatinate and minify js
gulp.task('script',()=>
   gulp.src("js/**/*.js")
   .pipe(concat("script.js"))
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(gulp.dest("js"))
  );

//all task in this file
gulp.task('default',['message', 'imageMin', 'sass', 'script']);

//watch command

gulp.task('watch', ['message', 'imageMin', 'sass', 'script'], function() {

 gulp.watch("images/**/*",['imageMin']);
 gulp.watch("sass/**/*.scss",['sass']);
 gulp.watch("js/**/*.js",['script']);

});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
after that in your_main_sass_file.scss use this
@import "abstractions/**/*";
@import "variables/**/*";
@import "base/**/*";
@import "layout/**/*";
@import "components/**/*";

where abstraction,variables,base,layout,components are the folder inside the sass folder all of them contain different .scss partial files
```

and your_main_sass_file.scss is outside these folders;
 hope this will work

Comment: is it for Gulp3 or Gulp 4 ? Because I actually use Gulp 3, and I've no time to update my code to use Gulp 4.